# How to set several variables to e,g, TRUE in cmake

Tags: cmake

is there a way to set several variables in CMake?

this doesn't work:

```
set(
VAR1 TRUE
VAR2 TRUE
)
```

Then `VAR1` will contain "TRUEVAR2TRUE"

I could of course use:

```
set(VAR1 TRUE)
set(VAR2 TRUE)
```

etc..
but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

For several variables with incremental numbers, you could create them in a [loop](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/foreach.html) like this

```
foreach(ITER RANGE 1 2)
    set(VAR${ITER} TRUE)
endforeach()
```

This will define `VAR1` and `VAR2` and set both of them to `TRUE`.

Now this is hardly worthwhile for only two variables.

Instead of using incrementally numbered variables, you could use CMake's [list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html) in the first place and access the values by index.

What's considered "better" depends largely on how the variables are used.

Comment: Ok, lists is maybe something I could use. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could maybe help. If you found my answer useful, consider giving it an upvote or accepting it.